# What's the proper way to check if GetItem didn't find the record in dynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Here am trying to find a better way to write the getItem in dynamoDB , how to return the record not found and can we store both record and 'not found' string on same response variable

```js
public async getItem(){
let response;
try {
      dynamoClient = new AWS.DynamoDB({
        region: 'us-east-1'
      })
      data = await dynamoClient
        .getItem(params)
        .promise()
        
        if(data.length == 0){
        respoonse =  'no record found'
        }else{
        respnse = data
        }
        
        
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.error('get error', error.stack)
    }
    
    
    return response;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is very relaxed in regard to types. Your code is fine for node.js to run, but IMO using inconsistent return values is a bad practice. Eslint for example has a [rule to check this](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return).

To address your code, one option would be to create a database response structure that contains required information. Simple examply would be such as

```
{
  data: <db-response> | null,
  error: "not found" | <some error> | null
  // ... other field as needed
}
```

With this you also can address the issue when the code throws an exception. Just include enough information to `error` field.

On the client side of `getItem()` you can check for presence of `data|error` as you need.

This is a very simple approach to fulfill your requirement. On the downside, it adds logic on the client side as a burden to check the presence of data/error.

Another option to consider is using Maybe structure. Basically the response might have data or not. In any case, it is the client's responsibility to handle the possible data not found case and act accordingly.

Note: The Maybe in itself is off topic for this thread and I'm not going to explain it further. Searching the web will give you a lot better resources with more detailed information than I could ever provide.